# SpringBoot rabbit connection timeout issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

My spring boot application throws connection timeout error, and it is never able to connect. The other interesting problem I see is, it is never picking up the connection timeout property defined in spring app properties.

```
  org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:74) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:309) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:577) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1431) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1412) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1388) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1123) [spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:98) [spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1329) [spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:76) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:110) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:292) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:824) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:736) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:293) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Here is my java config,

```
    @Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitConfig {

    private final String exchange;
    private final String queueName;


    public RabbitConfig(
            @Value("${exchange.name}") String exchange,
            @Value("${queue.name}") String queue) {

        this.exchange= exchange;
        this.queueName=queue;
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, true);
}

@Bean
DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(queueName);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(RabbitAdmin admin,CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    connectionFactory.setCloseTimeout(10000);
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    //container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}

//    @Bean
//    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
//        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
//    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin admin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }


}
```

And my spring application properties look like,

```
spring.rabbitmq.host = 127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port = 15672
spring.rabbitmq.username = guest
spring.rabbitmq.password = guest

exchange.name=myExchange
queue.name=myQueue

spring.rabbitmq.cache.connection.mode=CONNECTION
spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.size=50
spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.checkout-timeout= 10000
```

Rabbit is up and running on 127.0.0.1 on port 15672, but the app is never able to connect.

Comment: Are you **sure** RabbitMQ has the **AMQP** port open on 15672? By default, 15672 shows the web UI (admin console) and the AMQP port is 5672. You might simply need to change your `spring.rabbitmq.port` to `5672`.

Comment: Oh man, I was killing myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, the AMQP port is 5672. Port 15672 shows the web UI (admin console). If you're using the default setup, adjust

```
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
```

[RabbitMQ networking configuration reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html)